DefineModel is acting strange
Is the following supposed to happen?
parent component:
<template>
 <child v-model:counter="counter" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from 'vue';
import child from './child.vue';
const counter = ref(0);
</script>

child component:
<template></template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {onMounted} from 'vue';
const counter = defineModel<number>('counter');
onMounted(()=>{
counter.value++; // now the counter should be 1
console.log(counter.value) // prints 0
});
</script>

After updating the model counter from inside the onMounted hook, the value of the model is still 0. This is strange and why is it like this?
Vue Playground

Apparently this is the expected behavior.
According to this issue posted in GitHub, under the hood, the DefineModel macro mutates the model via the parent component. Therefore , the nextTick is supposed to give the latest value.
<script setup lang="ts">
import {onMounted, nextTick} from 'vue';
const counter = defineModel<number>('counter');
onMounted(()=>{
    counter.value++; // now the counter should be 1
    console.log(counter.value) // prints 0
    nextTick(()=>{
        console.log(counter.value) // prints 1
    });
});
</script>

